# Pyspark inserting into Hive table record duplications issues

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to insert the record first time it is fine matched with RDBMS table count but if it is multiple time execute scripts, we are getting duplicate records and count mismatched with RDBMS table vs Hive Table.

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("tablename",overwrite =True)
```

Comment: can you please confirm on your environment ? databricks ?

Comment: no, it is cloudera

Comment: is your df has duplicated rows? if yes try to drop it